# Using Master Detail Flow, how do i make buttons i added in activity_item_detail.xml clickable

Tags: android, master-detail

I added some buttons to the activity_item_detail.xml off of the Master-Detail Flow, but it doesn't seem like the buttons are clickable. Even if I add android:onClick attribute it doesn't seem like the buttons are being pressed.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/item_detail_container"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".ItemDetailActivity" tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button7"
    android:layout_gravity="left|bottom" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button8"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button9"
    android:layout_gravity="right|bottom" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried your code and it seems working. Please find below the source code.

activity_main.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/item_detail_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ItemDetailActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left|bottom"
        android:text="New Button 7" 
        android:onClick="buttonSevenClicked"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
        android:text="New Button 8"
        android:onClick="buttonEightClicked" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
        android:text="New Button" />

</FrameLayout>
```

And in activity,

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void buttonSevenClicked(View v){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Button 7", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();         
    }

    public void buttonEightClicked(View v){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Button 8", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();         
    }
}
```